# Swift - OpenUrl for Google map doesn't show the direction (loading forever)

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I'm working on an iOS app where I need to open Google Maps to navigate to a location. I'm using the Scheme for iOS `comgooglemaps:\\`

Here is my code :

```
guard let url = URL(string: "comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=\(latitude),\(longitude)&directionsmode=\(travelMode)"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) else {
    return
}
UIApplication.shared.open(url)
```

But the problem is, once on Google Maps, the route is not showing on the map and Google Maps is loading forever if Google Maps wasn't already started. I'm using iOS 14.4.1.

This happen using the current user location and I need it

Edit for Universal Link: That's an idea too and I forgot to precise that I test it but there is a bug too. When the user doesn't accept location on Google Maps, instead of asking to complete the form for the origin point and set the destination, Google Maps return a totally blank form. On Android, the destination is set.

Comment: Have you checked to url? Is latitude and longitude in the correct format? It works for me regardless of whether Google Maps was launched before or not. This URL for example uses cologne as the destination: `comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=50.9576191,6.8272392&directionsmode=driving`.

Comment: This seems to be a GoogleMaps issue - I can confirm it on iOS 14.4 (also using the above example) - if the maps app is killed (not in the background) when you open the url, it will not show directions.

Comment: As a workaround, you can pass in your location to `saddr` param.

Comment: @MarekLisik The problem is when you don't have the current location of the user in your app... The workaround doesn't cover all possibilities but it's in the good way.

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/ios-urlscheme#universal-links-and-google-maps), you can also use `https://` links, as Maps support universal links. This seems to work fine, even while the `comgooglemaps://` url fails to load directions. Check [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started#parameters_1) for information on individual parameters. Here's an example matching your query:

```
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=\(latitude),\(longitude)&travelmode=\(travelMode)
```

Comment: That's an idea too and I forgot to precise that I test it but there is a bug too. When the user doesn't accept location on Google Maps, instead of asking to complete the form for the origin point and set the destination, Google Maps return a totally blank form. On Android, the destination is set.

Comment: That's unfortunate, I guess you might be left monitoring for a fix on the Google  Maps side (looks like that's where the issue is), or consider Apple Maps in the meantime?

Comment: It's what I was thinking for Google Maps, I will let it that way, thanks. I already use Apple Maps as a choice for the user :S